# Reference and Object in Java

Tags: java, object, reference

I am stuck at this portion.

```
class1 cls = new class2(); //class1 reference and class2 object
```

I know it is method overriding, But somehow not getting a clear vision what is actually going behind the scenes. I need a clear view as I can implement this where I need it. Any answer with example makes more clear concept. Thanks

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

Comment: You should read a good beginners book on Java programming before going near an editor and compiler.

Comment: Double docs! Also the names you have used are misleading. Something like `Class1 myObject = new Class2();` might make it easier to understand

Comment: Yeah, method declaration was wrong :) , ok now

Comment: @Sunny There isn't anything in your post that coul be called a "method declaration". Seriously, you shouldn't try doing anything specific before learning the basics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, its not method overriding, its like the following case,

1. `Horse` is an `Animal`. In Java you will say that `Horse` is a sub-class of `Animal`.
2. Now, lets say there is a horse whose name is "lightening". In some java sense you can write `Horse horse1 = new Horse( "loghtening" );`
3. But again... since every horse is an Animal.. so you can also write, `Animal animal1 = new Horse( "loghtening" );`
4. But then... what is the difference... ? Well... the difference is that when you are referring to an animal, you should talk about things which apply to all animals... not just horses. In any conversation... If you say something "horse-specific" about any animal... people will get confused. For example you can not just say "I had a ride on back of my pet animal Lightenning"... well... Others don't know Lightening is horse and you can not ride on all animals. Similarly, In Java even if `Horse` class has a method `rideOnMyBack` you can not call `animal1.rideOnMyBack()`... because in your conversation with Java... `animal1` is referred as an Animal

Answer (score 1):

The line of code in your question is often referred to as "programming to an interface". It is not "method overriding".

Search for this on, e.g., this site. E.g. look at. [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Answer (score 0):

Your question's code snippet should be `Class1 class1 = new class2();` not `class class1 = new class2();` as you can't assign any object to reference of `class`.

And **This is not method overriding**.

**Method Overriding** is something where you write a method in your class with  the same name, same parameters and same return type as one of the methods in its super class.

In your case, it's called **Type Casting** or **Auto boxing/ unboxing**. Suppose in your case `Class2 extends Class1` then when you will instantiate Class2 actually in memory there will be three objects created in the memory as per shown in the image below -

[image]

Now when you'll do `Class1 class1 = new class2();` actually reference of Class1 itself will be assigned. But according to the code you'll have a feeling of assigning object of Class2 in Class1 which is impossible in java.

As a thumb rule, you can assign to a reference only the object of that class or null, nothing else.

Now for accessing methods and variables -

- Priorities will always be given to methods of subclass. So if you have 2 methods with same name, same parameters then method of sub class will be invoked. This is called method overriding.
- Instance variables will always be accessed of the same class.

Comment: "Priorities will always be given to methods of subclass. So if you have 2 methods with same name, same parameters then method of sub class will be invoked. This is called method overriding" --------- This is a lot helpful buddy, absolutely worthy...though I made a mistake in the question :D but it,s ok now

Comment: Good to know that u got what you needed. you can upvote and accept the answer then. :)